# Why is python failing to skip first line in csv when there are newlines?

Tags: python, file, csv

I'm reading a csv file with python. I am skipping the first row, which is simply descriptive metadata. This is what I'm doing:

```
f = open(in_file)
#skip the first row
next(f)
#...some data processing
```

This works fine, but when the first row contains a cell with a newline character (for example:

```
some random cell
with a new line
```

The `next(f)` command returns all the cells up to and including this cell, but ends with `some random cell \n`' and doesn't remove any further cells in this first row. Why is this happening and how can I ensure the entire first row is removed regardless of newline characters in the cells?

Comment: because line iterators aren't aware of csv syntax. use built-in `csv` module instead, or, even better, pandas `read_csv`.

Comment: There are no "cells", you are dealing with a text stream. Use the `csv` module to handle csv formatted text

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a very basic and general problem (that's why you were downvoted I guess): **in modern operating systems, files are not typed: their content is just a sequence of bytes, and the meaning of those bytes is given by the applications** (binary vs text is still a antic distinction in Windows). This crucial and basic property of the operating system is masked by the Desktop application (Windows, Gnome, KDE, Finder, ...): I click on a ".csv" file, the desktop opens Calc (or Excel), I click on a ".exe" file and Windows launches the program, ... But that's just conventional. At OS level, the content of a file is just bytes, nothing more. There is a very good reason for that: typed files at OS level would help you one week, and you'd have to struggle against it for the rest of your life.

Back to your question: Python won't decide for you that your "xyz.csv" file should be opened with some specific care. It opens the file and let you read it as bytes or characters and you have to handle the content yourself. Luckily, Python comes with "batteries inside" and provides the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to wrap your file:

```
import csv

with open(path, 'r', encoding='...') as f: # set the encoding ofthe file, e.g. utf-8
    reader = csv.reader(f) # you may set the delimiter, quote char, etc.
    for row in reader:
        ... # do what you want with each row
```